# Multi line parentheses in latex

Tags: equations

I would like to have more than on line in a big paranthesis, how can I do that. I have test this code but doesnt work for me:

```
\begin{equation}
p \big[ i, j \big]=min\Bigg(

 p \big[i-1, j-1 \big] + 2 \times d \big ( i, j \big)\\
 p \big[ i, j-1 \big] + d \big( i, j \big) \\
 p \big[i-1, j \big]+d \big( i, j \big) \Bigg)

\end{equation}
```

Comment: You need to `\usepackage{amsmath}` and then use the `align` (or `align*`) environment, not `equation`.

Comment: And delete the blank line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\left` and `\right` to get automatically sized delimiters, however they have no effect in this situation. You can also use an `array` environment to have a grid in one line, and the `pmatrix` to have it wrapped in parentheses. If you have

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

in your preamble, you can use

```
\begin{equation}
  p[i,j] = \min
  \begin{pmatrix}
    p[i-1,j-1] + 2\times d(i,j) \\
    p[i,j-1] + d(i,j) \\
    p[i-1,j] + d(i,j)
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

I'm assuming you're using `min` as an operator.

Comment: Please get rid of all seven pairs of `\left` and `\right` instructions: they don't actually affect the sizes of the brackets and parentheses -- all they do here is to insert extraneous whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
     p \big[ i, j \big]=  min\Bigg( & p \big[i-1, j-1 \big] + 2 \times d \big ( i, j \big)\\
                                    & p \big[ i, j-1 \big] + d \big( i, j \big) \\
                                    & p \big[i-1, j \big]+d \big( i, j \big) \Bigg)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```